# Is there a specific word for friends who you play cards or board games with regularly?

Tags: word-choice

Can I call them regulars? Or is there a specific term?

Cambridge dictionary defines "regular(n.)" as

> someone who often goes to a particular event or place, such as a shop
>   or restaurant:

So can I say: Sometimes I cover for one of my grandma's *regulars* and play Mahjong with them.

Comment: I think 'regular players' might be safer. 'Regulars' is usually only used in a setting that most people are pretty familiar with (the pub, a restaurant, a barber's ... certain places of ill repute).

Comment: 'regulars' sounds fine to this AmE ear

Comment: In UK I used to belong to a card [**school](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/school) (5)**. I met some friends every week to play cards. The **school** refers to the group of people, not the location.

Comment: I wouldn't say "one of my grandma's regulars" because saying that would make my grandma sound like a prostitute, and even if my grandma were a prostitute, I certainly wouldn't ever want to suggest I sub in for one of the johns who typically frequent her and then play Mahjong.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - "I sometimes cover for one of my grandma's mahjong regulars" would avoid that problem.

Comment: How about “gaming buddies”?

Answer (score 1):

The following is understood and grammatical to this AmE ear"

*Sometimes I cover for one of my grandma's **regulars** and play Mahjong with them.*

The [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/161414?redirectedFrom=regulars#eid) supports the sense of such usage: a **regular**

> noun - a person who does something or goes somewhere on a regular
>   basis; a regular or habitual customer, visitor, participant, employee,
>   etc. Now esp.: a person who habitually frequents a particular bar,
>   restaurant, etc.

As in:

*Glancing over the crowd, he saw many of his regulars.*

and

*This gentleman was one of his regulars.*

Comment: Yeah, but when they're a woman's, *regulars* is very often used as a euphemism for  clients who frequent her as a prostitute, so I would steer clear of the term in this instance for that reason.

Comment: @lbf Benjamin provides one potential usage, but *regular* is pretty generalized. A regular means different things to a *bartender*, a *barber*, a *conductor*, a *shopkeeper*, and a *group leader*. Women can be any of these. It would take a specific context for me to assume that *regular* meant sex client.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two problems:

1. how to refer to the people that meet regularly
2. how to refer to someone within that group of people

Problem (1) can be solved by referring to the group as a "Mahjong group". It implies all the requisite information - Mahjong is a game, so members are assumed to play, and "group" implies regular attendance. Problem (2) is then trivial, because any **member**, **player**, **lady**, **man**, **someone** in that group is automatically an habitual player.

> Sometimes I cover for a player in my grandma's Mahjong group.